# htaccess: serve webp image instead of jpg or png if webp exist results in 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webp

I generated *.webp files that are named exactly like their png or jpg source. Then I added this to my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # Does browser explicitly support webp?
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome [OR]

 # OR Is request from Page Speed
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Google Page Speed Insights" [OR]

 # OR does this browser explicitly support webp
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp [OR]

 # AND does a webp image exists?
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp -f

 # THEN send the webp image and set the env var webp
 RewriteRule (.+\.(?:jpe?g|png))$ $1.webp [NC,L]

</IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_mime.c>
   AddType image/webp .webp
 </IfModule>
```

What I expect:

all jpg files load normal e.g /test/marc.jpg If a webp with the same name exists, serve a webp file via url /test/marc.jpg

This works of the webp file exists. But if I delete a webp file I get a 404 on the jpg or png url. Even old jpg or png urls then give a 404. Example:

```
/www/media/
  .htaccess
  marc.jpg
  marc.webp
```

http://domain/marc.jpg serves the webp. I test this from chrome with cache disabled. When I delete the marc.webp I get a 404 on http://domain/marc.jpg Why? RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f should fix this, right?

Comment: Looking at this, I can't see how it ever works, because $1 is going to refer to the whole of "marc.jpg", so try to load "marc.jpg.webp", not "marc.webp". I also wasn't aware that you could use the $1 from the RewriteRule inside the RewriteCond like that, but maybe you can?

Comment: The original script had this at the beginning: 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

But I removed the RewriteBase. But with RewriteBase it does not work at all. Even in my root /

Comment: And /test/marc.jpg.webp doesn't work either.

Comment: As a side note, testing the user agent, particularly for something as generic as the word "Chrome", is a bad idea; the real Google Chrome should be sending a correct Accept header (which you test for further down anyway), and there is no particular reason to assume any other browser with that in its user agent will handle WebP images correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are not looking for the files you describe:

```
 # AND does a webp image exists?
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp -f

 # THEN send the webp image and set the env var webp
 RewriteRule (.+\.(?:jpe?g|png))$ $1.webp [NC,L]
```

In both of these, `$1` refers to the first captured match in the RewriteRule, which in this case is `(.+\.(?:jpe?g|png))`. If you request, "marc.jpg", that whole string matches, and will be placed in `$1`. The two lines therefore evaluate as:

> If the file "marc.jpg.webp" exists, respond with "marc.jpg.webp"

Since it doesn't, the rule will not be run.

---

The condition you wanted was:

> If the file "marc.webp" exists, respond with "marc.webp"

So you want `$1` to contain only the "marc" part of the requested file; that's just a matter of moving the closing parenthesis:

```
 RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,L]
```

---

This doesn't explain why your rule appeared to work, and stopped working when you deleted a file. I suspect you have another rule somewhere else which is confusing the situation.

Comment: You were right: there was another rule fastest cache plugin that altered these urls. thanks!