# Serve webp as jpg for not appended filename extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, jpeg, webp

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930922/htaccess-serve-webp-image-instead-of-jpg-or-png-if-webp-exist-results-in-404) when I put what's needed for serving jpg/png as webp in the `.htaccess` file, it doesn't load! I have `image.jpg`, `image.jpg.webp`, and `image.webp`. It's working with the second one but what I want is the third one. So I deleted the second one but now it doesn't load the webp file. Each time I'm checking, I'm clearing the cache, so that's not the problem. My browser also supports WebP. I don't know why when I right-click to save the image it shows webp when the second file exists, but when I delete the second one in order to use the third one it shows jpg to be saved!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
    RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I thought maybe the regex which is `(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$` is wrong but that's correct as I tested it and the result was:

```
  0 => "example.com/image.jpg"
  1 => "example.com/image"
  2 => "jpg"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
> RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,NC]
> ```

The problem is that you are always checking for the existence of `image.jpg.webp` in the preceding condition, but rewriting to `image.webp` in the *substitution*.

You need to check for the existence of `image.webp` instead (the same file you are rewriting to).

However, this does depend on where the `.htaccess` file is located (unless we add another *condition* to extract the necessary part of the URL/file-path<sup>***1**</sup>).

For example, if the `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/wordpress` subdirectory then:

```
:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,NC,L]
```

However, if the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root then remove `/wordpress` from the *TestString* in the preceding *condition*.

You should include the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive.

This rule should go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker). Although if the `image.jpg` file always exists then it shouldn't matter.

---

#### <sup>***1**</sup> Generalised version

The rule could be changed to work regardless of where the `.htaccess` file is located (although the `RewriteBase` directive would need to be adjusted accordingly or removed altogether). However, we would need an additional *condition* in order to extract the necessary part of the file-path. For example:

```
:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,NC,L]
```

The `%1` backreference (as opposed to `$1`) contains the value of the first capturing group in the preceding *CondPattern*. So, in the above, it contains the absolute file-path that the requested URL maps to, less the `.jpg` suffix.

---

#### **UPDATE:** Both images / rules...

> ...how to include both of them? I mean first to check if the `image.webp` exists to return this! if not, to check if the `image.jpg.webp` exists to return that. Otherwise the `image.jpg`

You basically just need both rules. With the highest priority image  rule first (ie. `image.webp`).

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/

# 1. Rewrite to "image.webp" if it exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,NC,L]

# 2. Rewrite to "image.jpg.webp" if it exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.webp -f
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|png)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.webp [T=image/webp,NC,L]
```

I changed your original rule (#2) from using `REQUEST_FILENAME` since this isn't necessarily reliable (eg. if a non-existent `.jpg` file in a non-existent directory was requested, but the corresponding `.webp` existed in a parent directory then it would result in an erroneous rewrite - an edge case).

Rule #2 is also not dependent on `RewriteBase` and would work regardless of the location of the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thank you very much @MrWhite :) Could you please update the answer and tell me how to include both of them? I mean first to check if the `image.webp` exists to return this! if not, to check if the `image.jpg.webp` exists to return that. Otherwise the `image.jpg`.

Comment: @kodfire You're welcome. I've updated my answer to allow for both images / rules.

Comment: Again thank you! Just a quick and basic question, after running `RewriteRule` of #1, `RewriteCond` of #2 won't run? If yes, so what if we have other rules to be run on some conditions? If no, can we make it like if..else statements in order not to run the second one if the first rule is true?

Comment: @kodfire the second `RewriteRule` (not `RewriteCond`) is still processed but it won’t match (because the request has already been rewritten by rule #1) so does nothing.

Comment: Is it possible for the second one not to be processed? @MrWhite ?